# How can I install AMD ATI Catalyst Display Driver In Ubuntu 13.10 64bit?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon, fglrx

Hello I was wondering if I can install AMD Catalyst 13.1 Proprietary Linux x86 Display driver. I am running Ubuntu 13.10 Beta 64bit and the card in question is listed under the AMD Radeon HD 3000 series. I have tried the most recent driver and when the computer loads it hangs and never loads so I have to restart in recovery and remove it to boot into my computer. I want 3d acceleration to work is the reason why I am trying to get this to work as well as being able to adjust for overscan problems with my tv.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Take a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx and also here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI

Answer (score 6):

You can't very easily. AMD hasn't updated the drivers for  the AMD Radeon™ HD 4000, HD 3000 and HD 2000 Series  they only support up to xserver 1.12 and the kernel up to 3.4.  Ubuntu 13.10 is using (at the time of writing on a freshly upgraded system) Xserver 1.14 and kernel 3.11.  The last supported version of ubuntu is the 12.04 LTS (without the Quantal packages! get 12.04 not 12.04.2 or .3)  Some people have had lucking using this repo (https://launchpad.net/~makson96/+archive/fglrx) with a modified driver and downgraded xserver on 12.04.2 12.10 and 13.04 but not yet with 13.10. Check back later and maybe they'll have got 13.10 working. But even if they have it may not work for you, it doesn't work for everyone!

Comment: Thanks for the reply I am going to try it and see if it works. I will try and downgrade the xserver and kernel to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Settings in the Dash, or click the little gear in the launcher.  After that go to "Software Updates" and then click on the "Additional Drivers" tab.

Now select the fgrlx-updates radio item.

That should do it.  I have a 7950 and it works perfectly with that.  Can't speak directly to your card, but this is the easiest and best way to install any video driver really.

[image]

Comment: the method you suggested is the method I tried first before posting here. The reply from it was could not find a driver that works with my card. Thanks for the reply though.