# Install ATI Radeon HD in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon, fglrx

I saw [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181190&p=12823425#post12823425).

And downloaded [this](http://www2.ati.com/drivers/beta/amd-catalyst-14.1-betav1.3-linux-x86.x86_64.zip) in [AMD page](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86_64).

Which of these two should I use?, my graphic card is ATI Radeon HD 5450.

Also, I don't understand what exactly amd64 means when talking about this graphic card, my CPU is a corei5, I think this amd64 is not related with my CPU, but any insight in the topic is greatly appreciated.

## Update

I tried first link, previously I [reinstalled](https://askubuntu.com/a/88619/78882) video related packages and it worked again

But now is completely broken.

## Update 2

[reinstall](https://askubuntu.com/a/88619/78882) worked, I was forgetting `*` in `apt-get remove fglrx*`.

## Update 3

Another option I found is [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/360088/78882).

Comment: I can advise you take a look at this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver and this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD

Comment: A core 15 would be a 64-bit CPU, use the amd64 kernel and software unless you have installed the 32-bit version of Ubuntu. Check with `uname -p`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second link was the answer, I extracted file, then:

```
cd Downloads
chmod +x amd-driver*.run
./amd-driver*.run
```

I selected the first option, install driver, NOT build package.

Answer (score 0):

"AMD64" means a 64-bit operating system. Download the correct driver (86 or 64 bit), right click and select properties. Then in the permissions tab, check off "Allow Executing File as Program". Then double-click the file and select installing the driver on top of "X.org". Then go through the process of installing, and at the end make sure you reboot.

I've dealt with Linux driver problems for the last 5 years. In case something goes wrong, in grub select "Older Linux Versions" and boot the latest Kernel from there. The system should boot and work properly. Then start a terminal and type the following commands:

sudo apt-get autoremove fglrx --purge

sudo reboot

You should then try either the "Additional Drivers" Ubuntu program to install AMD drivers or try installing the drivers through steam. If you still have issues, email me and I'll be glad to help!